# Create a global email function in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want an email function that I can call from any controller when any route is made a request. I have put same email function in many routes having a small difference in parameters. How can I create a global email function that I can call from anywhere inside my project to send an email?

```
router.post('/route1',(req, res, next) => {


    const email = 'something';
    const subject = 'something' ;
    const body = 'something';

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'something', // sender address
        to: 'something', // list of receivers
        bcc:['something','something'],
        subject: subject, // Subject line
        html: "<p><h2><b>Hello</b></h2><p>
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.json({ success: false, msg: 'Failed To Send Email ! Try Again.' });
        }
        else {
            return res.json({ success: true, msg: 'Mail Sent Successfully' });
        }
    });
});
```

I want to create a global function for this functionality, where I can simply pass these parameters.

Comment: Package it as  a [module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)?

Comment: Okay. How can I do that in express?

Comment: Read the provided link in my comment; Nothing to do with express either, this is a Node.js concept.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, It worked like butter.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a js file. You can name it `mail.js`. The code will be as following:

```
const sendEmail = (email, subject, body, opt) => {

    // Set default options
    let options = {
        from: 'defaultfrom@test.com', // sender address
        to: email, // list of receivers
        bcc: ['defaultbcc@test.com'],
        subject: subject, // Subject line
        html: body
    };

    // Merge options if any new option provided
    // This will add fields or override old fields
    if (opt) options = { ...options, ...opt };

    // Send email function
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log(`Mail couldn't send. Error: ${err}`);
            return reject();
        };

        console.log(`Mail sent successfully`);
        return resolve();

    });

};

// Export function
module.exports = { sendEmail }
```

This function will return a promise. You can use this function in any of your routes simply by requiring. A usage inside of your route may be as following:

First, require it,

```
const { sendEmail } = require('./mail');
```

Then; use it,

```
sendEmail('email@test.com', 'Subject', 'Body', { from: 'xyz@test.com' })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Mail sent');
        res.status(200).send();
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log('Error:', e);
        res.status(400).send();
    });
```